# Label ID doesn't work with one activity in AndroidStudio

Tags: android

In Android Studio I have the `MainActivity.java` and the `activity_main`, but the ID of the items doesn't work. **How I can solve it?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ids like this in the xml:

```
android:id="@+id/place"

android:id="@+id/view"

android:id="@+id/list"
```

New id will have `@+`, when you're referring to an id which is already created, you will have just `@`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

Instead of

```
tools:context=".httpclientdavid"
```

Because the context attribute should be the same as the activity...